# Ignore part of a python tuple

Tags: python, tuples, iterable-unpacking

If I have a tuple such as `(1,2,3,4)` and I want to assign 1 and 3 to variables a and b I could obviously say

```
myTuple = (1,2,3,4)
a = myTuple[0]
b = myTuple[2]
```

Or something like

```
(a,_,b,_) = myTuple
```

Is there a way I could unpack the values, but ignore one or more of them of them?

Comment: `a, _, b = myTuple` is a pretty common idiom. To be honest, I don't see much wrong with it.

Comment: What's the problem in having `_ == 2`? Nobody is ever going to use `_` after in the code.

Comment: What if I want to ignore two parts of the tuple? I'll update teh question

Comment: @Rik ...unless they use the [gettext](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#gettext.install) library.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your solution is fine in my opinion. If you really have a problem with assigning _ then you could define a list of indexes and do:

```
a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
idxs = [0, 3, 4]
a1, b1, c1 = (a[i] for i in idxs)
```

Answer (score 87):

I personally would write:

```
a, _, b = myTuple
```

This is a pretty common idiom, so it's widely understood. I find the syntax crystal clear.

Comment: I'd like to note that in the python interpreter `_` is assigned to the result of the last expression (so if you type `'hi'` and hit enter then `_  is 'hi'`) until you do something like this in which you assign a value to it, then it will never work as it did before.

Comment: @2rs2ts for completeness: `_` will work again as it usually does *when your locally-assigned variable `_` leaves scope*, e.g., when an enclosing function ends. To force this to happen at a specific point in your program, you can use `del _`; this explicitly deletes your locally defined variable, `_`, which unmasks the global value, `_`.

Answer (score 27):

You can use `*_` to capture an unknown number of elements.

```
first, *_, one_before_last, _ = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Gives:

```
first = 1   
one_before_last = 8
```

Comment: Correct, but I'd clarify that this only works for Python3.

Comment: there is only python 3

Comment: Your above statement is demonstrably false. Whether we like it or not, there exist myriads of legacy codes using Python2, and it would be helpful to know what is backward compatible and what isn't (that's why IDE's offer exactly this information).

Comment: This only works with **one** single-asterisk item in the unpack list (which receives every element not explicitly accounted for, one by one). This is because if there were more than one, there would be no way to know how many of the source elements should go into each; in the face of ambiguity, Python refuses the temptation to guess.

Answer (score 7):

Note that you can slice the source tuple, like this instead:

```
a,b = some_tuple[0:2]
```

Comment: Great! In case at various entries, it cold be easy like:
`a,b = myTuple[0], myTuple[3]`