# How can I add the values of the same key to one another from a file within a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My text file looks like so (Number of goals each person scores at different dates):

```
1/23/15 Jack G2
3/15/15 Sally G5
1/23/12 Jack G1
3/15/14 Sally G3
```

What I want to do is turn that file into a dictionary, I have done:

```
Goal = {}
with open("(goals_per_person.txt") as goal:
    for line in bill:
        (name,score) = line.split()
        Goals_per_person[int(name)] = goals
```

But I'm not sure, how I can ignore the date because it's not needed. After I get the respective goal per person i want to add that onto each other and print it. So add the values of the same key

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. It seems like you're asking two separate questions here: 1) how to ignore the date, 2) how to add to a dict value instead of overwriting. Both of those have already been asked: [Ignore part of a python tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9532576/4518341), [Trying to split strings into key:value pairs and sum the values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61488191/4518341). As well your existing code doesn't seem to work. Please ask one question at a time. See [ask] for more advice.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to just disregard the first column of the split, throwing the value into a dummy variable

```
dummy, name, score = line.split()
```

Instead of `dummy`, a common convention is to use `_` as the variable, or use that as a prefix (`_dummy`) to indicate you won't use it.

As an FYI, you will run into the other problems

- `name` is not an integer
- `Goals_per_person` should be `Goal`
- You want to put `score` into the dictionary, not `goals`